# Rails generate rspec:install fails on rails 4.2 on Ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When I run Rails generate rspec:install on rails 4.2 on Ruby 2.1.5 I get:

```
/home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1/lib/inherited_resources/responder.rb:2:in `<module:InheritedResources>': uninitialized constant ActionController::Responder (NameError)
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1/lib/inherited_resources/responder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1/lib/inherited_resources.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7aef260921d4/lib/active_admin.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7aef260921d4/lib/activeadmin.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-7aef260921d4/lib/activeadmin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/biznz/api/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to follow this rails/ember tutorial and I don't know what I did wrong?! 
https://devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux-part-1-the-api-and-cms-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources', branch: 'rails-4-2'
```